# Detect Windows N and KN Editions

Tags: uwp

How can a UWP (C#, XAML) app detect if it is running on a N or KN edition of Windows 10?

Things I have tried:

Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Helpers.SystemInformation

System.Environment.OSVersion

APIs present on all Windows 10 systems:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-apis

APIs present on some Windows 10 systems:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-extension-apis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, there's no such API for you. You could submit a Feature Request on [WPDev UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/)

With Windows 10, your app could use [ApiInformation class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation) relevant APIs to check whether a [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.metadata.apiinformation.istypepresent#Windows_Foundation_Metadata_ApiInformation_IsTypePresent_System_String_), [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.metadata.apiinformation.ismethodpresent#Windows_Foundation_Metadata_ApiInformation_IsMethodPresent_System_String_System_String_), [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.metadata.apiinformation.ispropertypresent#Windows_Foundation_Metadata_ApiInformation_IsPropertyPresent_System_String_System_String_), [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.metadata.apiinformation.iseventpresent#Windows_Foundation_Metadata_ApiInformation_IsEventPresent_System_String_System_String_) or [API contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.metadata.apiinformation.isapicontractpresent#Windows_Foundation_Metadata_ApiInformation_IsApiContractPresent_System_String_System_UInt16_) is supported by the current operating system.

For example, if you want to check whether `Windows.Devices.Input.Preview.GazeDevicePreview` class is supported, you could use `ApiInformation.IsTypePresent` method like the following:

```cs
if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Devices.Input.Preview.GazeDevicePreview"))
{
    //call appropriate APIs
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Xavier. Your method certainly works for checking API/type/method presence. However, I want to know if the UWP app is running on Windows 10 N or KN.

Comment: For now, there's no such API for you. You could submit a **Feature Request** on [WPDev UserVoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: I have edited your answer to include your comment and marked it as correct. Thank you!